# What sort of object represents a table row from a joined table query?

Tags: object-oriented, naming

I have a conceptual problem here. When i query my database, i often do so with joins. So a result set row might look like

```
+------------+--------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+---------+
| CustomerId | CustomerName | MaterialId | Sales | Quantity | Salesman | Manager |
+------------+--------------+------------+-------+----------+----------+---------+
```

This result contains properties that would appear in certain objects, like `Customer`, `Material`, `Invoice`, and `Salesman`. It wouldn't make sense to put all these properties into any one of the above objects. For example, having a `sales` property in an `Material` object breaks object cohesion in my opinion. A material's (in this context it's a mechanical/plastic part) properties should list its id, its manufacturer, which machine it's applicable to, etc. To have a sales property is unrelated, because sales only makes sense when you're talking about a customer.

Another caveat of my data is that I never work with individual invoices, but rather aggregated invoices over some period of time, grouping the invoices by customer and material. So even the keyword `Invoice` seems incorrect, because an invoice represents a specific point in time where a sale was made.

My problem is that I would like to have 1 object that has all these properties, but don't know how to give it an accurate name. What then, should this object be called? Something generic like `AggregateInvoice`? How do i accurately represent all these different properties as a noun?

Comment: If you don't mind long names, InvoiceDataGroupedByCustomerAndMaterial comes into mind (or sensible abbreviations).

Comment: `MaterialSoldToCustomer`? Or actually you seem to be grouping by the salesman and the manager as well so maybe `MaterialSoldByPeopleInvolved`?

Comment: InvoiceSummaryByCustomerAndMaterial? Or just InvocieSummary. Not sure of *Summary* or *Resume* can replace here (in meaning) the concept Aggregate.

Comment: What's the name of the query?  Usually the query gives an idea of what object(s) are returned.  GetCustomers(), GetCustomer(customerId).  That might help decide what the name of this is.

Comment: Is this another case for [CQS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)? I'd name it sort of `MaterialSalesQueryResult`; i also think i'd be a good idea to make these classes immutable (since changes to instances of it would be impossbile to reflect in the DB); Basically point your OR/M to a ready-only view.

Comment: It's just a record type.

Comment: Why create a new class?  What's wrong with an instance of a resultset?  How many different queries do you have?  Do you really need to distinguish them?